# Android - Add Custom menu to built-in Messages long press Context menu

Tags: android, sms

I wanted to write an app to encrypt all incoming Messages. So I received SMS and after encryption I put encrypted SMS on Messages inbox without any problem:

```
package org.appsroid.smsmodifier;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                String address = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                String body = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

                /*
                 * Some codes to encrypt body ...
                 */

                /*
                 *  Add Encrypted SMS to Messages inbox
                 */

            }

            // Delete plain SMS
            abortBroadcast();
        }                         
    }
}
```

Now, I need to add a custom content menu to built-in Android Messages context menu to let user to decrypt message body. Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no single "built-in Android Messages" app. There dozens, perhaps hundreds, across different device models. Few will have a context menu, fewer still will offer any means for you to modify it. Beyond that, there are many more SMS client apps available on the Play Store and elsewhere that the user may already be using.

Second, your "put encrypted SMS on Messages inbox" code will not work on Android 4.4+, unless you write a complete SMS client, as [only the SMS client can write to the SMS `ContentProvider`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).

Hence, you will need to write your own SMS client, both to be able to decrypt your messages and to be able to have it work at all on Android 4.4 and higher. Then, you will need to convince people that your SMS client, given its encryption capabilities, is worth using instead of their current SMS client.